# SELECT with JOIN taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, I want to grab common columns between these two tables for a specific date, I also want these grouped:

```
SELECT uv.keywordid, uv.competitionid
  FROM unique_views as uv
       JOIN signups AS s 
            ON s.keywordid=uv.keywordid 
               AND s.competitionid=uv.competitionid
 WHERE    uv.dt_created > "2014-02-27"
       AND s.dt_created > "2014-02-27"
GROUP BY 
       uv.keywordid, uv.competitionid
ORDER BY 
       uv.keywordid, uv.competitionid
```

Both keywordid and competitionid are indexed in the two tables. Both tables have around 11k records at this point, and most entries have the same keywordid and competitionid.

This query is locking my tables for ~20 seconds. What could I do to improve speed?

Comment: It may be helpful to show `EXPLAIN` of this query

Comment: What is the reason of using `GROUP BY`? Apparently you are not using any aggregate function.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `dt_created`? Are the indexes on `keywordid` and `competitionid` separate indexes or composite?

Comment: @AzizShaikh `GROUP BY all columns` is equivalent to using `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Add one index on each table containing the date column and the two int columns (in that order). And as @Aziz says, try chaning GROUP BY to DISTINCT.

Comment: Show us your excecution plan, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want distinct pairs of keywordid, competitionid having records in both table created after 2014-02-27. Use DISTINCT then, not GROUP BY.

Here is a method guaranteeing to select the distinct tuples from each table before doing the join. So this should be fast:

```
select keywordid, competitionid 
from
  (select distinct keywordid, competitionid from unique_views where dt_created > "2014-02-27") uv
inner join
  (select distinct keywordid, competitionid from signups where dt_created > "2014-02-27") s
using (keywordid, competitionid)
order by keywordid, competitionid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Twenty seconds seems like a long time.  I would suggest rewriting the query as an `exists` query.  This eliminates the aggregation and allows for some other optimizations.

```
select s.keywordid, s.competitionid
from signups s
where s.dt_created > '2014-02-27' and
      exists (select 1
              from unique_views uv
              where s.keywordid = uv.keywordid and
                    s.competitionid = uv.competitionid and
                    uv.dt_created > '2014-02-27'
             );
```

This assumes that there are no duplicate `keywordid`, `competitionid` pairs in signups.  If that is possible, then use this version:

```
select s.keywordid, s.competitionid
from (select distinct s.keywordid, s.competitionid
      from signups s
      where s.dt_created > '2014-02-27'
     ) s
where exists (select 1
              from unique_views uv
              where s.keywordid = uv.keywordid and
                    s.competitionid = uv.competitionid and
                    uv.dt_created > '2014-02-27'
             );
```

Next, create the following two indexes:

```
create index signups_dt_created_keywordid_competitionid on signups(dt_created, keywordid, competitionid);
create index unique_views_keywordid_competitionid_dt_created on unique_views(keywordid, competitionid, dt_created);
```

These indexes actually "cover" the query, so the indexes can be used for the processing rather than the original data pages.

Comment: Fantastic! Much better in the performance department. Considering dt_created is a datetime field, would you say it's a good choice to index that column? I was hoping to have this query with the additional where cases: dt_created>='2014-02-27 00:00:00' and dt_created<='2014-02-27 23:59:59'

Comment: @JorgAncrath . . . `dt_created` is in both indexes that I suggest.  The indexes will work on your clauses as well.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're not using any aggregation (e.g. SUM, COUNT), I'm not sure why you want grouping.

I'm also not sure what you mean when you say:

> and most entries have the same keywordid and competitionid.

Does that mean there are many duplicate keywordid/competitionid in both tables or that a given combination mostly exists in both?

My suspicion is that you're actually looking for distinct records rather than grouping. Without knowing the answers to my two questions above, it's difficult to give a precise response, but you might like to consider the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT keywordid, competitionid
FROM unique_views
WHERE dt_created > "2014-02-27"
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT keywordid, competitionid
FROM signups
WHERE dt_created > "2014-02-27"
```

would give you the distinct combinations in both tables. These could be joined together to give you:

```
SELECT a.keywordid, a.competitionid
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT keywordid, competitionid
  FROM unique_views
  WHERE dt_created > "2014-02-27") a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT keywordid, competitionid
  FROM signups
  WHERE dt_created > "2014-02-27") b
ON a.keywordid = b.keywordid and a.competitionid = b.competitionid
```

Comment: @thorsten-kettner gave almost the same query in his answer except that he used the 'using' keyword which is more correct and concise

Answer (score 0):

Let's supose that half of your data (5K) is sharing same key (uv.keywordid, uv.competitionid).
Then, your `JOIN` Condition (`s.keywordid=uv.keywordid AND s.competitionid=uv.competitionid`) its true for 5k*5k possible pair of records, that means 25M possible results that you have to serve ordered. I think you have a design problem in your query.